# SQL Server Partitioning, best practices for creating partition scheme's and functions

Tags: sql-server-2008, table-partitioning

I'm implementing Partitioning for the first time in SQL Server 2008r2.  I've several large tables that I am partitioning.

My main question is should I use the same Partition Scheme and Function for all these tables, or should I create multiple Partition Scheme's and Functions?

When I move older data to an different file group will having separate Scheme's and Functions make moving the data easier?

And what are some things that should consider when making this decision?

Comment: consider posting your question to serverfault's sister site for database-related stuff http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I have posted it there at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1023

Comment: You probably mistyped your link - it should be http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10239

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single schema and function and you alter that to move data around all the tables will be moved in a single shot instead of having to change all of them.